# Sight vector in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, vector, 3d

The problem I have is that I cant get "line of sight" vector in OpenGL. I've done some research and found that it should be Z vector after transformations, but it doesn't want to work. I've got this code to retrive velocity of the block( i want it to move foward from "camera"), but all the time it moves irrelevant to camera, but all the time same way compared to rendered world:

```
GLfloat matrix[16]; 
    glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
    GLfloat d = sqrt( matrix[8]*matrix[8] + matrix[9]*matrix[9] + matrix[10]*matrix[10]);
    xmov = matrix[8]/d;
    ymov = matrix[9]/d;
    zmov = matrix[10]/d;
```

What I've done wrong?

Comment: Well, if it's drawn relative to the world, move it relative to the world. Otherwise, I find it useful to split ModelView into Model and View matrices, and ignore the latter when I need this (so yeah, it will be Z coordinate)

Comment: It's drawn in camera position in the world. And now I want it to move the way camera is "looking", but all the time it moves ralative to scene not to camera. Sorry im new to OpenGl, maybe idk sth.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, now after you clarified what you really want to do, I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer:

You are probably used to something called `ModelView` matrix. Didn't it seem strange for you that it's essentially combined of two parts? Well, it was for me, and after I thought about it for a while, it made sense. The final vertex position is calculated like this:

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMat * ModelViewMat * VertexPos;
```

You see, there's no difference for OpenGL whether you move "camera" from origin by `[x,y,z]` or move objects by `[-x,-y,-z]` - you'll get the same results. It is however useful to distinguish a "camera" position as something that can be different from the origin.

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMat * ViewMat * ModelMat * VertexPos;
```

I think the most natural way to do it is, as I said, split the calculations into two matrices : `Model` and `View`. Every object on the scene now has to change the `Model` matrix, and camera position is set by changing `View` matrix. Makes sense?

I'll give you an example. If your camera is in `[5,0,0]` (which corresponds to `Translate(-5,0,0)`), and your object in `[-5,0,0]`, it will land 10 units from the camera. Now, when you move your camera further away from origin (increasing the first translation distance), distance between "camera" and the object grows.

The object translation is *the Model*, the camera translation is *the View*.

So it's not hard to come to conclusion, that if you want to *ignore* camera position, just strip the `View` part from the equation; every object will now be drawn *without* taking camera position into account, thus relative only to your viewport.

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMat * ModelMat * VertexPos;
```

Our hypothetical model will now land 5 units along the X axis from the viewport *regardless* of what you're currently "looking at", and that's, I think, pretty much what you wanted to achieve.

Anyway, you could probably use [a nice tutorial about it](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2007.html)

Comment: Thanks for explanation - clarifies a lot. Could you recommend me any book/tutorial explaining this topic better? Cause its main reason why my OpenGL learning is so slow. I just dont really get the coordinates and transformations.

Comment: The link is in the last line of the answer @user1701595 :) And since you're kind of new here, there's a tick button just below the score which marks answer as "accepted".